# HTML5 drag and drop multi-file upload grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

i'm using [HTML5 drag and drop multi-file upload plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/uploadr), to upload some files in my Grails application , but i want to save the uploaded files to DB but i don't know what is the object that is holding the uploaded files  i searched in **request and params** , here is my the tag in the **_form** view:

```
<uploadr:add name="myUploadrName"  controller="photos" action="save"   direction="up" maxVisible="8" unsupported="/my/controller/action" rating="false" voting="false" colorPicker="false" maxSize="204800" />
```

here is the **create** view :

```
<g:form  url="[resource:photosInstance]" enctype="multipart/form-data"><fieldset class="form">
                <g:render template="form"/>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="buttons">
                <g:submitButton id = "submitBtn" name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
            </fieldset>
        </g:form>
```

here is the save action :

```
def save(Photos photosInstance) {
    if (photosInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (photosInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond photosInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    request.getFileNames().each{
        request.getFiles(it).each { file ->
            // loop through all files selected
            println "name: $file.name Originalfilename: $file.originalFilename contentType: $file.contentType"
            photosInstance= new Photos(photo:file.bytes).save(failOnError:true)

        }
    }

    /*request.withFormat {
     form multipartForm {
     flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [
     message(code: 'photos.label', default: 'Photos'),
     photosInstance.id
     ])
     redirect photosInstance
     }
     '*' { respond photosInstance, [status: CREATED] }
     }*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A little hard to help when I don't have the controller code, but try this:

```
UploadedFile uploadedFile = UploadedFile.get(params.fileId)
if (!uploadedFile) response.sendError(404, "No uploaded file could be found matching id: ${params.fileId}.")

GridFSFile gridFSFile = uploadedFile.file
if (!gridFSFile) response.sendError(404, "No file attached to UploadedFile")
```

Comment: i added the save action to the original post

Comment: What are you getting while calling "save"?

Comment: As `photosInstance` is null , so it's executing the 1st if

Comment: Ah! so the issue is not with the multi-upload (yet..), it's with the domain class itself. Is your create() being called (and returning a new instance)?

Comment: Yes , create () was called and returning a new instance, the problem in the save() as i don't know the object that is holding the files.

Comment: I think you have MultipartHttpServletRequest - see http://grails-dev.blogspot.co.il/2013/07/multipart-file-upload-functionality.html for code samples

Comment: `request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest` is false